# In Sublime Text, how do you increase the number of lines of context returned by "Find All"?

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using the "Find All" feature in Sublime Text and I want to see a few more lines back from the find results. I can't find a setting for this -- is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could add newlines before and after the find regex as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To expand upon DarkWater's comment to your question:

Add new lines with a regex before and after your search string:

`.*\n.*\n.*search_string.*\n.*\n.*`

This will match 2 new lines before and after your `search_string`.

Make sure you enable regular expression searching in the find dialog. Also make sure that you escape any regex special characters in your `search_string`.

Comment: and a more generic way would be `(.*\n){2}.*search_string.*(\n.*){2}`

Comment: fwiw, Sublime Text 3 crashes everytime I try @zaboco's regex

Comment: strange, for me it still works, and I've tried many different inputs.
(using Sublime Text 3, build 3059 on Mac OS X)

Comment: this is complicated, impractical (you have to remember, or keep that regex somewhere), the "Show Context" button is the best choice, see Greg Sadetsky's answer

Comment: fwiw, yes, it's a decade later, but @zaboco's regex works fine for me in 2023, using Sublime Text 4 build 4143 

Answer (score 11):

Are you using the `Find in Files…` command from the Find menu (<kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)?

If so, there's an option in the find panel to see more lines than the result line alone -- the next to last button (there should be 5 option buttons in the find panel), which has a "Show Context" tooltip, should do the trick.

Comment: A good insight, but I am already using that -- what I needed was a way to increase the number of lines in the context.

Comment: clarify this in your question then please

Answer (score 8):

To expand on the solutions provided by @dasl and @zaboco

I found that this variation was more suitable.

Example:

```
(.*\n){0,2}.*search_string.*(\n.*){0,2}
```

This will match 0-2 new lines before/after your search_string. Adjust numbers as needed to provide more/less context, but always keep the 0 as the first number in the quantifier.

Again, make sure you enable regular expression searching in the find dialog.

(The original regexes required that 2 lines above/below are present in the files, and excluded some necessary files from the search results)